# About the realization of $SO(N)$ given by Daniel Bump in his book Lie Group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Thank for your interest for my question and thank you very much if you can answer me.

In his book p.187, Daniel Bump says that a realization (a representation) of $SO(2n)$ is given by the unitary matrice $g$ which verify $gJ^t g=J$ i.e. $J\,\overline{g}J=g$.

I understand why 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\left (
\begin{array}{cccccc}
e^{-i y}&&\newline
&e^{-i b}&\newline
&&e^{2 i y}\newline
&&&e^{-2 i y}&&&&& \newline
&&&&e^{ib}&&&& \newline
&&&&&e^{iy}&&& \newline
\end{array} \right ) 
\end{eqnarray}$$
with eigenvalues $1,e^{3 i y/2}, e^{-3 i y/2},1,e^{3 i y/2}, e^{-3 i y/2}$  is similar to a matrix belonging to $SO(2n)$ but I don't understand why 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\left (
\begin{array}{cccccc}
&&&e^{-i y}&&\newline
&&&&e^{-i b}&\newline
&&&&&e^{2 i y}\newline
e^{-2 i y}&&&&& \newline
&e^{ib}&&&& \newline
&&e^{iy}&&& \newline
\end{array} \right ) 
\end{eqnarray}$$
is similar to a matrix from $SO(2n)$ because its eigenvalues are $1,e^{3 i y/2}, e^{-3 i y/2},-1,-e^{3 i y/2}, -e^{-3 i y/2}$.